# Issues pairing Mi smart scale with Samsung Health app even though it is supported!

Tags: xiaomi, bluetooth-pairing, samsung-apps

I have mi smart scale XMTZC02HM and Samsung Health keeps telling me that it doesn't discover any accessories. Xiaomi scales are supported in Samsung Health app. When I exit the app and go to bluetooth settings of my Samsung mobile device, it instantly discovered the Mi scale but I can't pair the samsung phone with Xiaomi scale. FYI, the Mi smart scale pairs successfully with MiFit app but it doesn't with Samsung Health although Samsung Supports it. Is there any solution?

Comment: There's [a similar thread on Samsung's community forum](https://r2.community.samsung.com/t5/Samsung-Health/Mi-scale-not-pairing-with-Samsung-Health/td-p/866323). At this rate, I'd suggest contacting Samsung Support to ask for confirmation if it's really supported or not.